Radio Button Select in Table in React
I'm using React, MUI and Formik.
I have a table and how do I allow that only one radio would be selected by row?
This is my codesandbox: CLICK HERE
import { TableCell, TableRow, Radio } from "@mui/material";
import { FastField } from "formik";
import CustomTextField from "./CustomTextField";

const CustomTableRow = ({ row, index }) => {
  return (
    <TableRow
      key={row.id}
      sx={{
        "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 },
      }}
    >
      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
        <FastField
          name={`rows.${index}.attribute`}
          component={CustomTextField}
          fullWidth
          size="small"
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <FastField
          // checked={`rows.${index}.radio1`}
          name={`rows.${index}.radio1`}
          component={CustomTextField}
          type="radio"
          fullWidth
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <FastField
          // checked={`rows.${index}.radio2`}
          name={`rows.${index}.radio2`}
          component={CustomTextField}
          type="radio"
          fullWidth
        />
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
};

CustomTableRow.displayName = "CustomTableRow";

export default CustomTableRow;


To allow only one radio would be selected by row, each row have share the same name.

@Mina. Would you mind forking my codesandbox?

"It's likely that the Sandbox you're trying to access doesn't exist or you don't have the required permissions to access it."

@Mina. Pls try again. I just updated the settings


The radio elements on each row should share the same name.
Update the initialValues of Formik to have a state for the selectedOption
Update the validationSchema to validate the new selectedOption field
Pass setFieldValue and values to CustomTableRow provided by Formik to CustomTableRow
In the CustomTableRow component make a handleChange function which updates the selectedOption of that row depend on the selected radio.
Make the radio checked attribute update conditionally based on selectedOption of the row.

demo.js
import React from "react";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { Box, Button } from "@mui/material";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import { Formik, Form, FieldArray } from "formik";
import CustomTableRow from "./CustomTableRow";
import { array, object, string } from "yup";

const validationSchema = object().shape({
  rows: array().of(
    object().shape({
      attribute: string().required("Select an attribute"),
      selectedOption: string().required("Select an option"),
    })
  ),
});

const CustomTable = () => {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          rows: [
            { id: 1, attribute: "", selectedOption: "radio1" },
            { id: 2, attribute: "", selectedOption: "radio2" },
          ],
        }}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          console.log(values);
        }}
      >
        {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
          <Form>
            <FieldArray
              name="rows"
              render={(arrayHelpers) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                  <Box>
                    <Button
                      variant="contained"
                      onClick={() =>
                        arrayHelpers.push({
                          id: Date.now(),
                          attribute: "",
                          selectedOption: null,
                        })
                      }
                      startIcon={<AddIcon />}
                    >
                      Add New
                    </Button>
                  </Box>
                  <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
                    <TableHead>
                      <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Attribute</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Radio 1</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Radio 2</TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                      {values.rows.map((row, index) => (
                        <CustomTableRow
                          key={row.id}
                          row={row}
                          index={index}
                          setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                          values={values}
                        />
                      ))}
                    </TableBody>
                  </Table>
                </React.Fragment>
              )}
            />
            <Button color="primary" variant="contained" type="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default CustomTable;

CustomTableRow.js
import { TableCell, TableRow, Radio } from "@mui/material";
import { Field } from "formik";
import CustomTextField from "./CustomTextField";

const CustomTableRow = ({ row, index, setFieldValue, values }) => {
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFieldValue(`rows.${index}.selectedOption`, event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <TableRow
      key={row.id}
      sx={{
        "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 },
      }}
    >
      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
        <Field
          name={`rows.${index}.attribute`}
          component={CustomTextField}
          fullWidth
          size="small"
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <Radio
          checked={values.rows[index].selectedOption === "radio1"}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value="radio1"
          name={`rows.${index}.selectedOption`}
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <Radio
          checked={values.rows[index].selectedOption === "radio2"}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value="radio2"
          name={`rows.${index}.selectedOption`}
        />
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
};

CustomTableRow.displayName = "CustomTableRow";

export default CustomTableRow;


CODESANDBOX
